# Realm and MongoDB Atlas on NodeJS error: Failed to Login Cannot write to class Workstation when no flexible sync subscription has been created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, realm, nodes, mongodb-atlas

I'm running the following code and running into the following problem, would anyone have any idea what might be missing from being configured or something?

```
import Realm from "realm";
import 'dotenv/config'

export class Workstation extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = {
    name: "Workstation",
    primaryKey: "_id",
    properties: {
      _id: { type: "objectId", default: () => new Realm.BSON.ObjectId() },
      description: "string?",
    },
  };
}

async function main() {
  const app = new Realm.App({ id: "my-device-sync" });

  const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();

  try {
    const user = await app.logIn(credentials);

    const realm = await Realm.open({
      schema: [Workstation],
      sync: {
        user: app.currentUser,
        flexible: true
      },
    });

    const workstation = realm.write(() => {
      return realm.create(Workstation, { description: "Workstation1" });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to log in", err);
  }
}

main();
```

Erro:
Failed to log in Error: Cannot write to class Workstation when no flexible sync subscription has been created.